# How to get a time edging chart with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date, axis

Let's consider this example data:

```
time    value
09:30:00    a
09:50:00    b
10:00:00    c
15:00:00    d
15:20:00    e
```

I would like to have a time edging graph counting the "value" column. The x axis has to be a linear time progression.

I added a pivot chart and table, setting the x axis as "date format"
[image]

but as you can see Excel doesn't create a time linear axis, between 9.30 and 9.50 (20 minutes) there is the same gap as from 10 and 15 (5 hours).

Is there any way to set this linear?  Otherwise I have to prepare all possibile time-slots.
What "date format" of x-axis is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use xy (scatter) chart instead of linear.
Date format of x-axis on a linear chart requires whole numbers, which can be considered dates. Time values are represented by decimals < 1.
[image: Time on x-axis]